# Issue in payment form gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

We have a website where we provide the assignment service user are experiencing the issue of unable to go to payment gateway

https://www.ignougalaxy.in/handwritten-assignments-order

This is the link to the order form it is linked to paymnet gateway

Some of the users are saying that they cannot click on the payment button or pay now button

What would be the possible ussue tk thisss.  I have attached the error also please check.    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgRB9.jpg)

When our user are going to do the payment in our website we are experiencing thisss issue